# Diseñar página html con javascript para dilema del prisionero

Tags: javascript, html

Soy nuevo con js. Estoy empezando a intentar crear un experimento online para recoger datos de usuarios que jueguen al dilema del prisionero. Para tal propósito estaba intentando utilizar [jspsych](https://www.jspsych.org/) integrado en html.

En estos primeros pasos me gustaría:

1. Presentar al usuario la opción de "cooperar" o "traicionar" mediante botones.
2. Que su puntuación, acorde con las respuestas random del jugador-computadora ([y la matriz de pagos](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Prisoner's_Dilemma.jpg/330px-Prisoner's_Dilemma.jpg)), se fuera acumulando por un número de rondas determinado.
3. Guardar las respuestas por rondas y totales en un csv file (aunque esto lo dejaré para otra pregunta).

He conseguido hasta ahora escribir, en html integrando jspsych, los primeros pasos, es decir, una página html en que se explica el juego y luego se dan dos opciones al usuario (copio el código abajo).

Para el paso 2, he estado intentando diferentes pruebas con if statements, todas sin éxito.

Cualquier ayuda para hacer esto se agradece. No importa si la aproximación es diferente (por ejemplo, sin usar jspsych) y es sin embargo más funcional.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My experiment</title>
    <script src="jspsych-6.0.1/jspsych.js"></script>
    <script src="jspsych-6.0.1/plugins/jspsych-html-keyboard-response.js"></script>
    <script src="jspsych-6.0.1/plugins/jspsych-image-keyboard-response.js"></script>
    <script src="jspsych-6.0.1/plugins/jspsych-image-button-response.js"></script>
    <link href="jspsych-6.0.1/css/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  <script>

    /* create timeline */
    var timeline = [];

    /* define welcome message trial */
    var welcome = {
      type: "html-keyboard-response",
      stimulus: "Bienvenido al experimento. Pulsa una tecla para empezar."
    };
    timeline.push(welcome);

    /* define instructions trial */
    var instructions = {
      type: "html-keyboard-response",
      stimulus: "<p>En este experimento vas a jugar al dilema del prisionero. </p>" +
      "<p>Cuantos más puntos obtiene un preso antes saldrá de la cárcel </p>" +
          "<p> Si ambos cooperáis, ambos ganaréis 2 puntos. </p>" +
          "<p> Si ambos os traicionáis, ambos ganaréis 1 punto. </p>" +
          "<p> Si tú cooperas, y tu compañero traiciona, ganarás 0 puntos. </p>" +
          "<p> Si tú traicionas, y tu compañero coopera, ganarás 3 puntos. </p>" +
                "<p>Pulsa una tecla para comenzar.</p>",
      post_trial_gap: 2000
    };
    timeline.push(instructions);

    /* trial 1 */
    var trial = {
        type: 'image-button-response',
        stimulus: 'experiment_PS_files/payoff_matrix.jpg',
        choices: ['Cooperar', 'Traicionar'],
        prompt: "<p>¿Qué eliges?</p>"
};
    timeline.push(trial);

    /* start the experiment */
    jsPsych.init({
      timeline: timeline
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: No se lo que es el dilema del prisionero, por lo tanto, en mi caso, no se como sería, o pretendes que sea, el paso 2. Podemos asumir que son preguntas de verdadero/falso cambiado por cooperar o traicionar?

Comment: El dilema del prisionero no es más que un juego donde se puede "cooperar" o "traicionar" a un compañero de celda. En el experimento que intento hacer, tendríamos dos botones: uno para "cooperar" y otro para "traicionar". Y así, según las respuestas random de la computadora y acorde a la matriz de pagos que explico, se irían acumulando puntos. El código que he escrito llega hasta los botones. Muchas gracias !

Comment: Con respuestas random te refieres a respuestas que tienes que programar tu, no? o ya tienes algo que te da ese random?

Comment: Bueno. En este primer paso sería que el jugador-computadora "coopera" o "traiciona" aleatoriamente. Unas veces coopera y otras traiciona. En el futuro intentaré programar otras estrategias para la computadora. :)

Comment: Pues se me ocurre que puedes usar AJAX y un PHP. El Ajax llama al PHP que decide si es un 1 (cooperar) o un 0 (traicionar) en base a `rand()`. Después le mostraría al usuario el retorno y lo guardaría en la base de datos, para al final mostrarle el conjunto de resultados, de esa partida y de las siguientes, si tienen nombre los usuarios, si no solo de esa. No sé que tal andas con AJAX y PHP pero se me ocurre que es relativamente sencillo y rápido.